# Element not visible on IE 11with nightwatch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

We are using Nightwatch and working with Page objects. The tests are running without any issue on Chrome but element cannot be found on IE 11. We use css selector and custom tags (named data-testid) to call each element. IE 11 is starting correctly and loading the login page but cannot find any element on the page. Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Have you inspected the page on IE 11? There is a chance the tag is not actually there.

Comment: Yes, I have inspected the page on IE 11 and I can see the tag

Comment: I downgraded the IE webdriver to 2.53 and it worked!